# How to execute powershell invoke twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I was able to invoke powershell result one time but when I add second command to invoke again, it get an error exception that I can't invoke again because it already invoke earlier(`pipeline.Invoke();`). How can I make it work when I need to execute the first one to get the result I need to use then execute it again? I already tried `pipeline.Dispose();` and `pipeline.Commands.Clear();` they doesn't work.

here a C# codes,

```
protected void ButtonRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenName.Visible = false;
        string str = "";
        string ipAddress = "";
        string name = "";
        var tbids = (List<string>)Session["tbids"];

        //create a powershell
        Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runSpace.Open();

        RunspaceInvoke invoke = new RunspaceInvoke();

        Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

        Command invokeScript = new Command("Invoke-Command");

        //Add powershell script file and arguments into scriptblock
        ScriptBlock sb = invoke.Invoke(@"{D:\Scripts\Get-FreeAddress.ps1 '" + DropDownListContainer.SelectedValue + "' " + DropDownListIP.SelectedValue + "}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
        //ScriptBlock sb = invoke.Invoke("{" + PowerShellCodeBox.Text + "}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;

        invokeScript.Parameters.Add("scriptBlock", sb);

        invokeScript.Parameters.Add("computername", TextBoxServer.Text);

        pipeline.Commands.Add(invokeScript);

        Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();

        foreach(PSObject psObject in output)
        {
            ipAddress = ipAddress + psObject;

            foreach (var id in tbids)
            {
                try
                {
                    //str += Request[id] + "\r\n";
                    name = Request[id];

                    Command invokeScript2 = new Command("Invoke-Command");
                    //Add powershell script file and arguments into scriptblock
                    ScriptBlock sb2 = invoke.Invoke(@"{D:\Scripts\Set-IPAddress.ps1 '" + ipAddress + "' " + name + "}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;

                    invokeScript2.Parameters.Add("scriptBlock", sb2);

                    invokeScript2.Parameters.Add("computername", TextBoxServer.Text);

                    pipeline.Commands.Add(invokeScript2);

                    pipeline.Invoke();
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message that you get?

Comment: It said InvalidPipelineStateException was caught, `Cannot invoke pipeline because it has been invoked earlier`

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking different that I've seen before.  I think your invoke could be simplified.

Something like this:

Pass in:

```
@"{D:\Scripts\Get-FreeAddress.ps1 '" + DropDownListContainer.SelectedValue + "' " + DropDownListIP.SelectedValue + "}"
```

Into this:

```
private string RunPowerShellScript(string scriptText)
{
    // create Powershell runspace
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    // open it
    runspace.Open();
    // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
    // add an extra command to transform the script
    // output objects into nicely formatted strings
    // remove this line to get the actual objects
    // that the script returns. For example, the script
    // "Get-Process" returns a collection
    // of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.
    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
    // execute the script
    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    // close the runspace
    runspace.Close();
    // convert the script result into a single string

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```